# Trying to use random numbers to generate an outcome for Class module

Tags: python

I am having trouble returning to __mood field to generate a random mood for the animal objects. I don't know how to make it work, so what I have been trying to do is define it in the program titled animals.py

I have two programs: animals.py and animalgenerator.py

```
The animal generator asks for user input and produces a list that looks like:
What    type    of  animal  would   you like    to  create? Truman
What    is  the animal's    name?   Tiger
Would   you like    to  add more animals    (y/n)?  n

Animal  List
-----------
Tiger   the Truman  is  hungry
```

So far my program has worked, but it won't produce the moods.
__mood is a hidden attribute for the animal object.

check_mood: this    method  should  generate    a   random  number  between 1
and 3.
The random  number  will    be  used to set one of  three   moods:

If  the number  is  1,  the __mood field    should  be  set to  a   value   of  “happy”.

If  the number  is  2,  the __mood field    should  be  set to  a   value   of  “hungry”.

If  the number  is  3,  the __mood field    should  be  set to  a   value   of  “sleepy”.

Finally,    this    method  should  return  the value   of  the __mood field

Here is what I have on animals.py

```
class Animal:

    # The __init__ method initializes the attributes

    def __init__(self, name, mood, type):
        self.__name = name
        self.__mood = mood
        self.__animal_type = type

    def _animal_type(self, type):
        self.__animal_type = type

    def __name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def __mood(self, mood):
        for i in range():
            if random.randint(1, 3) == 1:
                self.__mood = 'happy'
            if random.randint(1, 3) == 2:
                self.__mood = 'hungry'
            if random.randint(1, 3) == 3:
                self.__mood = 'sleepy'
            else:
                self.__mood = 'happy'

    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def check_mood(self):
        return self.__mood
```

Here is what I have for animalgenerator.py

```
# This program tests the Animal class.

import animals

print("Welcome to the animal generator!")
print("This program creates Animal objects.")

def main():
    # Get the animal data
    animal_list = []
    find_info = True
    while(find_info):
        _animal_type = input('\nWhat type of animal would you like to create? ')
        __name = input('What is the animals name? ')
        more_animals = input('Would you like to add more animals (y/n)? ')
        if (more_animals != 'y'):
            find_info = False

        # Create an instance of animal class
        animal_list.append(animals.Animal(_animal_type, __name, __mood))

    animal = animals.Animal(_animal_type, __name, __mood)

    # Display the data that was entered.
    print('\nAnimal List\n')
    print('------------- \n')
    for animal in animal_list:
        print('' + animal.get_animal_type() + ' the ' + animal.get_name() + ' is ' + animal.check_mood() + '\n')


# Call the main function
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:  First, in __mood you have `for i in range():` but range requires at least 1 argument.  I think you probably don't want that at all, since there's no reason to be looping there that I can see.

Second, you probably need not generate a new random number for each check.  If you generate the random int from 1 to 3 a single time and see if it's 1, 2, or 3 you should be able to set the mood you want.

Third, `check_mood` doesn't ever call `__mood` to have it generate set a new mood.  Also, the way I read your assignment, er, requirements, you're supposed to generate the random number in check_mood then pass it to __mood instead of generating it within.

Forth, and probably more important than many of the above, particularly the third point, __mood can't be both a method name and attribute name.  Probably you don't want __mood to be a method and just have the body of it in check_mood.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this method can be written elegantly in 1-2 lines:

```
def __setmood(self):
    self.__mood = ('happy', 'hungry', 'sleepy')[random.randint(0, 2)]
    return self.__mood
```

But aside from that, I don't think you should use the same name for your method and your instance variable. When you do an assignment like `self.__mood = 'happy'`, you actually overwrite the binding to the method of your object. In other words, you can't call the `self.__mood()` method anymore even from within the class...

For example, the following code will raise a `TypeError` (`'str' object is not callable`):

```
class X:
    def __mood(self):
        self.__mood = 'happy'

    def callmood(self):
        self.__mood()
        return self

X().callmood().callmood()
```